# Expected value of edges with different colours at endpoints

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem is stated as such:
*" Given a graph G(V,E): an vertex is coloured red with probabillity 1/2". Prove that the expected value of number of edges that are their endpoints are coloured differently is $|E|/2$."*
There is a similar question : [Graph Theory: Expected value relative to the maximum of a coloring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635949/graph-theory-expected-value-relative-to-the-maximum-of-a-coloring)

My approach is different from the given answer in the link above but I have also a question about the given answer:
In the answer there is this sentence $\sum_{\forall e \in E}1/2 = e/2$.
**Why is it exactly** $e/2$ (I guess it means $|E|/2$ and not something less; If $X_{ij}$ is the edge between nodes $i, j$ then $X_{ij} = 1$ if they are not coloured the same, 0 otherwise so $E[X] = \sum_{\forall X_{ij}}X_{ij}1/2 \leq |E|/2$ **(right?)**

Now this is what I initially thought as a solution :  $X_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ i and j different colours}, p= 1/2\\
0, \text{ otherwise}, p=1/2
\end{cases}$
Let's define random variable $X$ as $X = \sum_{\forall X_{ij}}X_{ij}$.
$X_{ij}$ is **Bernoulli** with $p = 1/2$ so $X$ is **binomially distirbuted.**
$E[X] = \sum_{k = 0}^{|E|}k\binom{|E|}{k}1/2^k 1/2^{|E|-k} =  \sum_{k = 0}^{|E|}k\binom{|E|}{k}1/2^{|E|} =|E|/2$

*Not mathematical question".*
"Is it encouraged at such cases to ask questions above the answers that we do not understand or is it prefered to make new question as this? Because, in the past I think I was discouraged when I asked questions in the comments when the question was not mine. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer basically uses that the expected value is linear, i.e. $E[X + Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$ for two random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Therefore
$$E[X] = E\left[\sum_{\{i, j\} \in E} X_{ij}\right] = \sum_{\{i, j\} \in E}E[X_{ij}],$$
where the first equality uses definition of $X$, and the second equality follows from the linearity of the expected value.

Now for any edge $\{i, j\} \in E$, the probability that $i$ and $j$ do not have the same color is $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence $E[X_{ij}] = \frac{1}{2}$ and
$$E[X] = \sum_{\{i, j\} \in E}E[X_{ij}] = \sum_{\{i, j\} \in E}\frac{1}{2}.$$

The sum on the right hand side has $|E|$ summands, so
$$E[X] = \sum_{\{i, j\} \in E}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{|E|}{2}.$$

Note that at no point we have an inequality. Linearity of the expected value means that the expected value of a sum is *equal* to the sum of the expected values.

Your argument with the Bernoulli distribution is incorrect because the variables $X_{ij}$ are not independent. For example, if $G$ is a triangle, then it cannot happen that $X_{12} = X_{23} = X_{13} = 1$ at the same time.

Comment: thank you for pointing out why they are not independent makes sense. My approach i guess would be right only if I was trying to find the expected value of red coloured vertices